# Connecting a battery directly to a load as it's being discharged

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

[image]I have discovered the concept of load sharing after already ordering my boards and this poses a few quick questions. I don't have the schematic readily available but is a relatively simple circuit and I feel I can explain the situation somewhat well. I apologize in advance if something is unclear or if this is a redundant question yet this seems somewhat specific.

I am using an MCP73831 to charge a small, tiny, 40 mAh Li-ion pouch cell. I have connected the load directly in parallel without a P-channel MOSFET (a mistake most likely). The load is a small LED (20 mA) in the collector of an NPN transistor.

The base of this transistor is connected to the output of a Hall sensor (DRV5055) with a few resistors throughout this circuit. That's about it.

If the sensor doesn't detect a strong enough magnetic field, the transistor will not allow current to flow through this led, thus the load of the entire circuit is practically negligible (besides any sink from powering the Hall sensor).

Should I revise this schematic so I don't potentially damage my battery and/or components?

Is my theory correct that the load would be almost "0" with no magnetic field present near the Hall switch? My intuition tells me that this is still a bad implementation just due to the fact the sensor could pick up stray EM signals and may have unpredictable behavior when charging.

Just as a note, this is just a small circuit for self use that will probably not be charged often (if this changes anything). Anyways, any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated and I can provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing has nothing to do with "load sharing". Load sharing is when you connect power supplies in parallel, and that is not what you are doing.

What you *are* asking is whether you can connect a battery directly to a load as it's being discharged. (I changed your title to reflect your actual question.)

The answer is: yes, no problem. That's because your load is so small.

Had your circuit included a large load, then the answer would be more nuanced, as the solution may have called for a "[power path circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=power+path+circuit)".

Comment: [This](https://www.microtype.io/lithium-ion-battery-charger-circuit-load-sharing/), and a few other sources seem to contradict what you're saying. I'm new to the concept so I can't refute what you're saying but now I'm a bit more confused. The charging power supply is not in parallel with the battery (first image from that source) yet is considered to be sharing the load with the battery. The MCP73831 sits in between the charging supply and the battery in my circuit which is described as not a good idea from that site.

Comment: That source is using the term in a way that is not commonly understood.  This is what the term "load sharing" has always meant: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/easy-balanced-load-sharing-for-three-or-four-supplies.html. Though now I see that "current sharing" is a more common term.

Comment: @Weegeemaan32 --  Your comment made me doubt my understanding of 'load sharing". So [I asked](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651330/is-load-sharing-when-2-power-supplies-are-connected-in-parallel-or-when-a-bat) and the only [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651330/is-load-sharing-when-2-power-supplies-are-connected-in-parallel-or-when-a-batt/651333#651333) agreed with my understanding of what 'load sharing" means.