# Is "load sharing" when 2 power supplies are connected in parallel or when a battery is connected indirectly to the load?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, load, terminology

I see the term "load sharing" used in two completely different cases:

1. When 2 power supplies are connected in parallel, a technology that ensures that each delivers half of the load current: [Easy Balanced Load Sharing for Three or Four Supplies, Even with Unequal Supply Voltages](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/easy-balanced-load-sharing-for-three-or-four-supplies.html) (A.k.a., "current sharing".)
2. When a battery is connected indirectly to a charger and a load, a technique to turn off the battery and keep the load on: [Lithium Ion Battery Charger Circuit: Load Sharing](https://www.microtype.io/lithium-ion-battery-charger-circuit-load-sharing/). (A.k.a. "power path".)

Which of these two is the industry-accepted definition of "load sharing"?

Comment: (We were lectured about 1b: transformers of same ballpark power connected in parallel. There were restrictions about vector group I forget.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Load sharing" is named after a solution to common meatspace problem: trying to move a heavy thing by lifting it up and carrying it. If it's too heavy for one person, you get two. Or three. All lift the same thing *at the same time.* By analogy, both power sources simultaneously supply power in parallel, such that neither exceeds its current capacity. In both situations, they're sharing the load.

Switching different power sources in and out of circuit, but only using one at a time (#2 in your question)?  I've always called that "power multiplexing." [Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvae51a/slvae51a.pdf) agrees.

Without getting too deep into the [linguistic weeds](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), "sharing" seems to imply the same-time use of an object or set of objects (e.g. "let's share this bowl of chips"), as opposed to "taking turns" which implies using the same object at different times. EE's, of course, say "multiplexing" instead, but the meaning is the same.

Colloquially, "sharing" is often used for both, but that's probably just because "car multiplexing" is hard to say. Nonetheless, TI's app note and the wide number of Google hits for "power multiplexing" confirms that there's already a name in widespread use for #2.

Comment: Liked very much the way you wrote this up! It also includes the situation where multiple BJTs in parallel emitter-follower configuration (using small-valued emitter resistors) to help 'load share' the required load current, even. You included things within the definition and helped to exclude other things. So you drew out a boundary, too. Nicely handled!